# the variable only have it value inside while loop?

Tags: java, variables

```
static void parse(String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileReader fileReader=new FileReader((fileName));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    String string;
    StringBuilder myString = null;
    while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                
        myString =stringBuilder.append(string);
        String h=myString.toString();
        **System.out.println(h);**
        }

    }




static void parse(String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileReader fileReader=new FileReader((fileName));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    String string;
    StringBuilder myString = null;
    while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                 
        myString =stringBuilder.append(string);
        String h=myString.toString();
       }

       **System.out.println(h);**  
    }
```

when I try the second part of the code, it print out nothing.
how can I get the whole h String outside of the while loop? Is it I have to declare the variable h as instance variable instead of local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialised h inside the while loop You cannot access it outside the loop

```
while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                 
        myString =stringBuilder.append(string);
        String h=myString.toString();
       }
       System.out.println(h);
```

You can use it this way

```
String h;
 while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                 
           stringBuilder.append(string);
           }
       h=stringBuilder.toString();
       System.out.println(h);
```

Comment: "myString =stringBuilder.append(string);"
this is not concatenation but overwriting?

Comment: while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                 
            myString =stringBuilder.append(string);}
this code should make myString with all the whole text or just one line of text? I thought it suppose to create a string (myString) with all text available in the entire file

Answer (score 2):

no need to create instance variable. just put h outside the loop:-

```
static void parse(String fileName) throws IOException{
FileReader fileReader=new FileReader((fileName));
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
String string,h=null;
StringBuilder myString = null;
while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                
    myString =stringBuilder.append(string);
    h=myString.toString();
    }
   System.out.println(h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your h variable inside your while loop.  Therefore, every iteration of the while loop will create a new h variable scopped to that iteration.

You won't be able to access the h variable outside the while loop unless it is declared outside the while loop.

Keeping in mind, that the way you have it written though, the h variable is being overwritten every iteration as well, so you're end result would be whatever was put in h last.

In the long run, this code could be cleaned up a lot as well, and you wouldn't even need h

```
static void parse(String fileName) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((String line = br.readLine()) != null) {                 
        sb.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());  
}
```

You'll have to check my syntax, but that should be cleaner.

Comment: anyway I can write my code that it is not overwritten every iteration??

Comment: long story short, no.  Depends what you're really trying to do with h.  sb is already storing the file contents, so what is h really for?  If you wanted to store each individual line some where, I'd recommend stuffing them into something like a string array you can view individually.

Comment: sorry, I shouldn't have said no...you could of course just concatenate the string to h instead of overwritting it...however, I really don't understand the point as the lines are already being built in sb.

Comment: i am trying to get the 10 alphabet combination of every frame from the sb. 
let say the string is "abcdefghijk", i try to get "abcdefghij" and "bcdefghijk".

Comment: That will require a lot more manipulation than just reading the line into a variable.  Which you're already doing without h (i.e. String line).  I'd toss the StringBuilder idea out, if you mean "every line" instead of "every frame", then you can keep the loop the same and just manipulate the String line variable using subString or something.  Those the parts into a List<string> and you're gold.